# regularity of finite measure on borel sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

**Problem:**

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal B(\mathbb{R}^n))$. $\mu$ is called regular if:

i) $\mu(K)<\infty$ for $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ compact

ii) $\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(U):A\subseteq U\text{, U open}\}$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb{R}^n)$

iii) $\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subseteq A\text{, K compact}\}$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb{R}^n)$

iv) $\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(C):C\subseteq A\text{, C closed}\}$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Show that (ii),(iii),(iv) are equivalent and that if $\mu$ is finite, it is regular.

**Ideas:**

(iii)=>(iv) since every compact set is closed.

(ii)=>(iii): We only need to show that  $\mu(A)\le\sup\{\mu(K):K\subseteq A\text{, K compact}\}$ since the other way follows because of monotonicity. Not sure where to go from here.

I would appreciate any hints.